# Uniformly bounded variance and strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

Assume:  $\eta, \epsilon_1{,}...,\epsilon_n$ are independent with uniformly bounded variance.

Define: $$q_j=\eta + \epsilon_j, \qquad   j=1,\ldots,n$$

and  $$\overline{q_{-i}}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j \not=i}^n q_j, \qquad i=1,\ldots,n$$

Now by the strong law of large numbers, $\overline{q_{-i}}$ goes almost surely to $\eta$. Why is this the case? Thanks!

Here is an image of the proof i try to understand:
[image: proof]

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Presumably you're asking about the a.s. limit as $n \to \infty$, but what's happening to $i$? Is it fixed, or varying with $n$, or are you asking for convergence to be uniform in $i$ in some sense?

Comment: Is $E[\epsilon_i]=0$? Otherwise, I doubt it is true.  If so, the $\eta$ is largely irrelevant (just subtract it) and the $i$ does not look particularly important, leaving you with $\frac1{n-1} \sum\limits_1^{n-1} \epsilon_j$ and a more conventional strong law of large numbers result

Comment: I think you need the $\epsilon$ to have expectation zero.

Comment: Thanks! I posted an image of the proof i try to understand. In the paper it is not explicitly assumed that the expectation value of $\epsilon$ is zero.Then I make this assumption additionally so that the proof is clarified